# How to get value of password from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a website with registration and login. So I have a database where users information in stored. Now I want to get some info from this database. To be exact I want to get users password using PHP code. Right now my code is following:

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT password FROM users');
    echo mysql_result($result, 4);
?>
```

I get this message, when I try to run my code:

```
Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 4 on MySQL result index 8 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Praks\seaded.php on line 20
```

How could I make it work?

Comment: Why are you trying to jump to a specific row instead of using a WHERE user=? query?

Comment: u are selecting one field and jumping to 4th ?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that do not have 5 passwords rows stored in your database. so you can try :

```
 echo mysql_result($result, 0);//return first password from your query result
```

or you can do like this to echoing all passwords:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT password FROM users');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("password: %s ", $row["password"]);
}
```

**notice:** all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should move to [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).